# How to save data from textbox to database with its format in C#

Tags: c#, database, richtext

I have a textbox with text "Hello World"; it is bold and italicized.

Let's say the text became "***Hello World***" with a red font color: How can I store this text in a SQL database and retrieve it later while preserving all formatting?

Comment: Is this a TextBox or a RichTextBox?